# Inefficient Python script eating up memory (I believe)

Tags: python

I created a simple Python script to log track listens in iTunes and it seems that it's pretty inefficient. I'm primarily a front-end developer, so this is clearly not my area of expertise. I know loops can cause problems in any language, so I assume that's the issue here.

If I run this script for a while (say, a couple of hours or more) the fan on my computer starts working overtime and won't stop until I kill the script.

Any idea what might be making this happen? Suggestions on how to optimize? Appreciate any help I can get.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import wx, sqlite3, datetime, threading
from appscript import *
it = app('iTunes')
from AppKit import *



# Create the DB
Tapedeck = sqlite3.connect('Tapedeck.db', check_same_thread = False)
TapedeckQuery = Tapedeck.cursor()
Tapedeck.execute('''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS plays (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, track_id TEXT, track TEXT, artist TEXT, album TEXT, genres TEXT, play_count INTEGER, rating INTEGER, skip_count INTEGER, year_released INTEGER, date_played DATE)''')
Tapedeck.commit()


def getSec(s):
    l = s.split(':')
    return int(l[0]) * 60 + int(l[1])


def addTrack(track_id, track, artist, album, genres, play_count, skip_count, year_released, date_played, rating):
    #print '        --\n        Position: {}\n      Length: {}'.format(it.player_position(),getSec(it.current_track.time()))
    TapedeckQuery.execute('''INSERT INTO plays (track_id, track, artist, album, genres, play_count, skip_count, year_released, date_played, rating) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)''',
    (track_id, track, artist, album, genres, play_count, skip_count, year_released, date_played, rating))
    Tapedeck.commit()


loop_int = 1.0
last_track = '0'

def listen():

    global loop_int, last_track
    threading.Timer(loop_int, listen).start()
    if it.player_state() == k.playing:
        # check to see if track was restarted
        if it.player_position() < getSec(it.current_track.time())/2 and last_track == it.current_track.persistent_ID():
            self.last_track = '0'
        # has the track played beyond the halfway mark?
        if it.player_position() >= getSec(it.current_track.time())/2 and last_track != it.current_track.persistent_ID():
            today = datetime.datetime.today()
            now = '{}-{}-{} {}:{}:{}'.format(today.year, '%02d' % today.month, '%02d' % today.day, '%02d' % today.hour, '%02d' % today.minute, '%02d' % today.second)
            print '\nArtist:        {}\nTrack:      {}\nAlbum:      {}\nGenres:     {}\nDatetime:   {}'.format(it.current_track.artist().encode('ascii','ignore'), it.current_track.name().encode('ascii','ignore'), it.current_track.album().encode('ascii','ignore'), it.current_track.genre().encode('ascii','ignore'), now)
            last_track = it.current_track.persistent_ID()
            addTrack(it.current_track.persistent_ID(), it.current_track.name(), it.current_track.artist(), it.current_track.album(), it.current_track.genre(), it.current_track.played_count(), it.current_track.skipped_count(), it.current_track.year(), now, it.current_track.rating())

listen()
```

Comment: Try running it through `python -m cProfile -o prof.dat <prog> <args>` for a while, and you'll get file that gives you calls and how long each call took in CPU seconds.  To view it interactively, you would want `python -m pstats prof.dat`.  Take a look at that, then see if you can isolate the parts in which performance is acting up.  A sorted (by cumulative time) .dat file would be helpful to isolate any issues as well.

Comment: Firstly, have you actually determined whether it runs out of memory? Does it have a large memory usage when you come back two hours later?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import wx, sqlite3, datetime, threading
from appscript import *
```

`import *` is frowned upon as it makes it difficult to trace where names came from.

```
it = app('iTunes')
```

I recommend avoiding abbreviated names like `it` its hard to figure out what it means later.

```
from AppKit import *



# Create the DB
Tapedeck = sqlite3.connect('Tapedeck.db', check_same_thread = False)
TapedeckQuery = Tapedeck.cursor()
Tapedeck.execute('''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS plays (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, track_id TEXT, track TEXT, artist TEXT, album TEXT, genres TEXT, play_count INTEGER, rating INTEGER, skip_count INTEGER, year_released INTEGER, date_played DATE)''')
Tapedeck.commit()
```

Generally, performing actions at the module level is frowned upon. You should do it in a main function.

```
def getSec(s):
```

Python style guide recommends lowercase_with_underscores for function names. Also, don't needlessly abbreviate.

```
    l = s.split(':')
    return int(l[0]) * 60 + int(l[1])
```

I'd have done:

```
minutes, seconds = s.split(':')
return int(minutes)*60 + int(seconds)
```

I think its easier to see what's going on

```
def addTrack(track_id, track, artist, album, genres, play_count, skip_count, year_released, date_played, rating):
    #print '        --\n        Position: {}\n      Length: {}'.format(it.player_position(),getSec(it.current_track.time()))
    TapedeckQuery.execute('''INSERT INTO plays (track_id, track, artist, album, genres, play_count, skip_count, year_released, date_played, rating) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)''',
    (track_id, track, artist, album, genres, play_count, skip_count, year_released, date_played, rating))
    Tapedeck.commit()


loop_int = 1.0
last_track = '0'

def listen():

    global loop_int, last_track
```

Avoid global variables. You should generally only be using globals as constants.

```
    threading.Timer(loop_int, listen).start()
```

Python isn't Javascript. Instead of playing with threads, use time.Sleep(1) to sleep for a second between each attempt. Put everything in a loop. It'll be easier to follow.

```
    if it.player_state() == k.playing:
        # check to see if track was restarted
        if it.player_position() < getSec(it.current_track.time())/2 and last_track == it.current_track.persistent_ID():
            self.last_track = '0'
```

self?

```
        # has the track played beyond the halfway mark?
        if it.player_position() >= getSec(it.current_track.time())/2 and last_track != it.current_track.persistent_ID():
            today = datetime.datetime.today()
            now = '{}-{}-{} {}:{}:{}'.format(today.year, '%02d' % today.month, '%02d' % today.day, '%02d' % today.hour, '%02d' % today.minute, '%02d' % today.second)
```

The datetime has a formatting function which may be better suited to that

```
            print '\nArtist:        {}\nTrack:      {}\nAlbum:      {}\nGenres:     {}\nDatetime:   {}'.format(it.current_track.artist().encode('ascii','ignore'), it.current_track.name().encode('ascii','ignore'), it.current_track.album().encode('ascii','ignore'), it.current_track.genre().encode('ascii','ignore'), now)
            last_track = it.current_track.persistent_ID()
            addTrack(it.current_track.persistent_ID(), it.current_track.name(), it.current_track.artist(), it.current_track.album(), it.current_track.genre(), it.current_track.played_count(), it.current_track.skipped_count(), it.current_track.year(), now, it.current_track.rating())

listen()
```

As for your actual problem. I don't know this appscript/AppKit you are using. But I'll speculate that under some circumstances iTunes stops responding. Maybe a dialog gets popped or something. As a result, each thread gets stuck waiting for iTunes. But because you set the timer as your first action, a new thread keeps getting started which also gets stuck. Eventually, your poor scripts piles many many threads and that explains the hang.

If you use the sleep method I suggested above, that should prevent the script from running many threads.

Answer (score 1):

You could run `ps` or `top` to find out how much memory, CPU your script consumes ([`psutil`](https://code.google.com/p/psutil/) allows to do it from Python).

If `app('iTunes')` supports it you could replace your polling interface with a callback on event e.g., a track change.

If not then you could remove `threading.Timer()` call and replace it with this code:

```
import time

while True:
    next_time = time.time() + loop_int
    listen()
    delay = next_time - time.time()
    if delay > 0:
       assert delay <= loop_int # break loudly on clock adjustments
       time.sleep(delay)
```

This code runs `listen()` function every `loop_int` seconds (approximately) or if `listen()` function takes us longer than `loop_int` seconds then it runs the next `listen()` call immediately after the previous one.